# Play two soundtracks, from an "mkv" movie, on two different devices

Tags: audio, mkv, video-player

I have "mkv" movies with two soundtracks, one English and one French.
I'd like to play the video and the French soundtrack on my TV and the English soundtrack on my bluetooth earphones.
Is there a player capable of doing that?